# Have you used JustCode?

Tags: resharper, justcode

Has anyone used [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) from Telerik lately?  This question has been asked about two years ago, but I'm sure the issues must have been resolved by now.  Especially referring to running it side by side with ReSharper.

Comment: Might want to see [this](http://dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2012/08/18/justcode-vs-resharper) and [this](http://blog.vyvojar.cz/ernest/archive/2012/08/17/resharper-vs-coderush-vs-justcode.aspx) and [this](http://www.paulmiles.net/2013/01/teleriks-justcode-review.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been using Resharper for a while now. I decided to try JustCode to see how it behave.

After a week of using JustCode, I am uninstalling it and returning to Resharper.

What I like about JustCode:

- A single window indicating all warnings/errors in entire solution.
- Performance seemed to be a bit better than Resharper.
- Refactoring is easier to get to.
- Projects can be excluded, or type of file
- Language can be excluded (such as XAML)

What I did not like about JustCode:

- Sometimes the underline used to open the option for fixing or refactoring is frustratingly hard to click since VS also puts an underline at the same spot (and it is the context menu of the latter that pops up).
- Cannot change an hint to be a warning instead.
- Saw some minor bugs
- JustCode was giving hundreds of false positive warnings in the XAML code (luckily I could turn the inspection of XAML off)

What I was missing from Resharper:

- Warnings about method parameter missing/mismatch from the documentation
- Hints to transform an expression into a Linq expression.
- When writing an opening bracket, resharper automatically adds the closing one and puts you on an empty line in between the two.
- When completing a method, Resharper adds the first parentheses. It also adds the last one if that method is parameterless.
- I am sure there is a bunch of other stuff that I can't remember now

You can install both Resharper and JustCode alongside. I first suspended Resharper before installing JustCode and used JustCode fine.  When I resumed Resharper and restarted VS, both were running together without error.

Together, Resharper was finding more than JustCode.
For example, JustCode did not give a warning for the following: `"Value assigned is not used in any execution path."`
It even missed an error: `"Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'."`  The expression was:

```
if ((bool)CanDoIt) // Here CanDoIt is a property of type int.
{
...
}
```

All in all, the tool is not bad.  I recommend it over not having any. But if you have the choice between Resharper and JustCode, go with Resharper... for the moment; JustCode is still young.

Comment: For your information, if you want all errors and warnings in your solution go the the Resharper > Inspect > Code Issues in Solution menu. This one can be filtered and ordered quite anyway you'd like to.

Comment: Also, if you want to exclude projects from global analysis you can use the Resharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings > Edit items to skip and select folders. This one could really use some improvement though. For example I wanted to exclude my Unit Test projects from the solution-wide usage analysis, but if you use this option for that you will also exclude them from the Rename features... Also, I don't understand why is that option defined in the Resharper options and not somewhere in the solution or project properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of JustCode's smart tag or turn off Visual Studio's smart tag in JustCode's options menu. I prefer to access VS's smart tag by using ctrl+., so it hasn't been an issue for me.